# How can I create a text link in a Knockout JavaScript table?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've got some KnockoutJS code working - it pulls in a list and binds it to a table.

For the table-data which displays the `name`, I would like that to be an `<a href=...>`, but not sure how. The name is still displayed. But you can click on it.

Here's my current code:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name()"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: price()"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: endsOn()"></td>
    </tr>   
</tbody>
```

nothing too crazy.

I have another property called `url` which contains the full `http://blah` URL to direct the users to. Also, I would like a new tab to open up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to remove data-bind attribute from `td` tag and put `a` with attr binding inside `td`:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td><a data-bind="text: name, attr: {href: url}" target="_new"></a></td>
        <td data-bind="text: price"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: endsOn"></td>
    </tr>   
</tbody>
```

P.S. You don't have to put `()` after property name in data-bind attribute if you don't construct expression.

Comment: btw, target="_blank"