# Django links in Knockout Table

Tags: django, knockout.js

I have read this post: [How can I create a text link in a Knockout javascript table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840376/how-can-i-create-a-text-link-in-a-knockout-javascript-table) along with a couple others.

But, I am missing something somewhere, or not taking the right approach.  I've included the relevant chunks of code for my problem.  I am trying to use the table generated by knockout to to either update a task or remove a task.  The remove part is working fine.  I am trying to get the update to link to another page that is used to update the task.  I cannot figure out what I need to do to get the link working properly in the update column.

I've tried several different approaches for how to put the url in the list of dictionaries that is passed to the KO model.  Any advice to steer me in the right direction?  If I am missing any information, please let me know.  Thank you.

Views.py

```
def TaskList(request, job_id):
    job_tasks = Tasks.objects.filter(parent=job_id)

    tasks_list = []
    for task in job_tasks:
        task_row = {}
        task_row['task_id'] = task.task_id
        task_row['t_name'] = task.name
        task_row['date'] = task.date_created
        task_row['state'] = task.state
        task_row['url'] = '{% url tracking:update_task task_id=task.task_id %}'
        tasks_list.append(task_row)

    json_tasks = json.dumps(tasks_list)

    if request.POST:
        json_data = request.POST.get('json_blob')
        obj = loads(json_data)

        task.task_id = obj.get("task_id")
        remove_task = Tasks.objects.get(task_id=task.task_id)
        remove_task.delete()

        messages.success(request, 'Task removed')
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Update</th>
        <th>Remove</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind "foreach: tasks">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: t_name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: date"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: state"></td>
            <td a class="btn" data-bind="attr: {href: url}">Update</a></td>
            <td button class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.remove_task">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

{% block javascript_variables_nocompress %}
window.TASKS = {{ json_tasks|safe }};
{% endblock %}

{% block javascript_compress %}
<script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'js/knockout/knockout.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(function() {
    var RemoveTaskModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.tasks = ko.observableArray(window.TASKS);

        self.remove_task = function(task) {
            self.tasks.remove(task);
            $("#json_blob").val(ko.toJSON(task));
        }
    }
    ko.applyBinding(new RemoveTaskModel());
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

HTML

Answer (score 0):

I would use `reverse` to do a reverse lookup of the URL for each task:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def TaskList(request, job_id):
    job_tasks = Tasks.objects.filter(parent=job_id)

    tasks_list = []
    for task in job_tasks:
        ...
        task_row['url'] = reverse('update_task', args=(),
            kwargs={'task_id': task_id})
```

Then your observableArray should be able to bind the property from the JSON to the anchor tag. You might also note that in your code sample, your td is malformed:

```
<td a class="btn" data-bind="attr: {href: url}">Update</a></td>
```

it should be:

```
<td><a class="btn" data-bind="attr: {href: url}">Update</a></td>
```